# C# Webclient Post to AWS API Gateway Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I am having some problems attempting to post to an API gateway endpoint.

On my API gateway I have my gateway all set up, and tested via the tool and am getting results and can verify that the step function is in fact executing the request appropriately.

```
{
  "executionArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:execution:DevStateMachine-XXXXXXXXXXX:c9047982-e7f8-4b72-98d3-281db0eb4c30",
  "startDate": 1531170720.489
}
```

I have set up a Stage for this for my dev environment and all looks good there as well. where I am given a URL to post against.

```
https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/assignments
```

In my c# code I have the web client defined as follows:

```
    public Guid QueueAssignment(AssignmentDTO assignment)
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(assignment);
            var content = new StringContent(data);
            var uri = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/assignments"
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                _logger.Info("Successfully posted to AWS Step Function");
                _logger.Info(response);
            }
            else
                _logger.Error("Error posting to AWS Step Function");
                _logger.Error(response);

        }
}
```

Everytime this post is attempted I get the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
```

Is there something I am missing in posting to this URI or some type of conversion I need to do? Im kind of at a loss on where to go on this on.